# IOS App Templates Shop(UI DESIGN)

Tags: ios, templates, user-interface

I was searching a website where they sell App Templates (Like website templates for a website, http://www.templatemonster.com/).
Are there websites like this?

Regards,
Stefan.

Answer (score 6):

Check these out:

- [App design vault](http://www.appdesignvault.com/portfolio-condensed)
- [CodeCanyon](http://codecanyon.net/category/mobile/ios?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort_by=sales_count&categories=mobile/ios)
- [Appdesignify](http://www.appdesignify.com/)
- [iOS Elements](https://ioselements.com/)

Comment: Yeah thanks for this, but it's the only website i found myself too, i was wondering there are more :(.

Comment: @StefanKoenen I just added another one. check them out.

Comment: You can also check iOS Elements template https://ioselements.com (our company ios template)